# Download from Amazon S3, AWS CLI or Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I have a list of folder names in a txt file like:

```
folder_B
folder_C
```

There is a path in S3 bucket where I have folders like:

```
folder_A
folder_B
folder_C
folder_D
```

Each of this folder has subfolders like:

```
0
1
2
3
```

For every folder in the text file I have to find folder in S3 and download content of its subfolder with the highest number only.

Doing this by python boto3 seems to be complicated.

Is it a simple way to do this by AWS command line?

Comment: Are you only downloading "the highest number only" because you previously copied the earlier folders? If so, you might consider using the AWS CLI `aws s3 sync` command that copies _all files_ that haven't previously been copied. It's a way of synchronizing files between two locations.

Comment: The hard part about doing what you describe in the CLI is the logic of "get the folder with the highest number". That is best done in a programming language.

Comment: No, I want do download only a folder with the highest number. If folder_A has subfolders: '0','1','2' then I want to download subfolder '2' and skip the rest. My local folder is empty.

Comment: As John mentioned, you need some programming logic to get the highest number.  Using bash, you can use `sort` and `head` like this : `ls | sort -r | head -n 1`

Comment: To where do you want to download the files? All to the same directory, or would it need to create directories for each folder and number? Or do the target directories already exist?

Comment: New directory has to be created for each folder in my txt file. Example: my_local_folder\folder_b\\(here is a content of the subfolder with the highest number). I forgot to mention that my local machine is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did. It is really bad but it works. I used both boto3 and aws-cli

```
import subprocess
import boto3

folders = []
with open('folders_list.txt', 'r', newline='') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        folders.append(line)

def download(bucket_name):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix="my_path/{}/".format(folder), Delimiter="/")
    subfolders = []
    for i in result['CommonPrefixes']:
        subfolders.append(int(i['Prefix'].split('{}/'.format(folder),1)[1][:-1]))
    subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'cp', 's3://my_bucket/my_path/{0}/{1}'.format(folder, max(subfolders)),
                    'C:\\Users\it_is_me\my_local_folder\{}.'.format(folder), '--recursive'])

for folder in folders:
    download('my_bucket')
```

Comment: Great! You can avoid calling the AWS CLI by iterating through the files within the Python code, but you'll need to pre-create any directories where the files are being saved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bash one liner (assuming the format of aws s3 ls has file name as the last column):

```
for bucket in $(cat folder.txt); do \
  aws s3 ls s3://bucket-prefix/$bucket | awk '{print $NF}' \
  | sort -r | head -n1 \
  | xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://bucket-prefix/$bucket/{} $bucket/{} --recursive \
  ; done
```

aws-cli takes care of creating the directories if they are missing. (Tested on Ubuntu)